# Use which schema to query V$OSSTAT

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I need to query the values of `V$OSSTAT` and am able to do so using tools like dbVisualizer. But when I take the identical query and put it into some Javacode I fail to find the table.

I had this problem before with specific application schemas and was able to solve this by putting the applications schema name in front of the table simiar to this: `SELECT NAME FROM FOOAPP.USERS`.

But in this case I simply don't know which schema to use for gaining access to `V$OSSTAT`. I tried prefixing the view / table with `SYS` and `SYSTEM` already.

```
SELECT STAT_NAME, VALUE, COMMENTS FROM SYS.V$OSSTAT
SELECT STAT_NAME, VALUE, COMMENTS FROM SYSTEM.V$OSSTAT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such object as `SYS.V$OSSTAT`, because `V$OSSTAT` is a public synonym.
Because of this, there is no need to use a schema specifier for it.
The actual view is called `V_$OSSTAT` (same for other V$ views as well).
If you want a user to be able to select from that view, grant the privilege on that:

```
grant select on sys.v_$osstat to user;
```